# How can I use a function in several UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, singleton

In nomal when i want to playSound in a View i have to:
- import AVFoundation
- make 2 function for helper method:

```
//    MARK: Audio Function

func configureAudioSession() {
    self.audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    var categoryError:NSError?
    var activeError:NSError?
    //        set category cho audio session
    self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError)


    //        set active cho audio session

    var success = self.audioSession.setActive(true, error: &activeError)

    if !success {
        println("error making audio session active :\(activeError)")
    }
}

func playSound(withName:String, ext:String) {

    if let songPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(withName, ofType: ext) {

        if let songURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: songPath) {

                        println("songURL: \(songURL)")
            var songError:NSError?

            //        Tao audioplayer

            self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: songURL, error: &songError)



            self.player.numberOfLoops = 0
            self.player.play()
        }


        //
    }




}
```

when i want to play sound i only call a function playsound.

But now, i want to playsound can be use in several View . I don't know how to that. I already tried to make a new Swift file call SoundFunction and add my helper playsound methods to my SoundFunction.swift:

```
    import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class SoundFunction {
    var audioSession:AVAudioSession!
    var player:AVAudioPlayer!

    func check() {
        println("check")
    }


    func configureAudioSession() {
        self.audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        var categoryError:NSError?
        var activeError:NSError?
        //        set category cho audio session
        self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError)

        //        println("error: \(categoryError)")
        //        set active cho audio session

        var success = self.audioSession.setActive(true, error: &activeError)

        if !success {
            println("error making audio session active :\(activeError)")
        }
    }

    func playSound(withName:String, ext:String) {
        //       Lay song path
        if let songPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(withName, ofType: ext) {

            if let songURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: songPath) {

                println("songURL: \(songURL)")
                var songError:NSError?

                //        Tao audioplayer

                self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: songURL, error: &songError)

                //                println("songerror:\(songError)")

                self.player.numberOfLoops = 0
                self.player.play()
            }


            //
        }
        //        Chuyen thanh URL
        //        println("songpath: \(songPath)")



    }
}
```

and after that I come back to my Views, and tried to call function from SoundFunction.Swift:

```
    SoundFunction.configureAudioSession()
```

but I got an error "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

I don't know how to call same function for several Views. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line `SoundFunction.configureAudioSession()` you are trying to call a class function. Which is not the case here, that's why you get an error (even if the message don't mention that).

Even if you fix that with `class func configureAudio...` you'll still might have an issue where you'll sound will stop play once you'll be out of scope.

In order to do what you want, you should make a `singleton`. The code you wrote for your `SoundFunction` seems to be a good start. A slight modification will complete it.

Here is a Q/A of mine : [Swift - AVAudioPlayer, sound doesn't play correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911968/swift-avaudioplayer-sound-doesnt-play-correctly)

With my comment at the bottom :

> `SoundPlayer.swift` : http://pastebin.com/eX4iv3S4 .
>
> To be used like so : SoundPlayer.sharedInstance.playSound().
>
> Currently it use only one sound (because that is what I wanted), but you could easily add a parameter to the playSound method for example.

Please, tell me if it helped you :)

**Edit :**

With my code you should : change the `playSound` method to add parameter(s) like you did in yours. Finally, make sure the category you apply to your `AVAudioSession` is the one that fits the most to you.

Answer (score 0):

From @Ichamp's advice. I successfully create a new SoundPlayer.swift file and using SingleTon to share function and use it from everywhere i want:

```
 import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class SoundPlayer {

    // Singleton in order to access the player from 'everywhere'
    class var sharedInstance : SoundPlayer {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : SoundPlayer = SoundPlayer()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    // Properties
    var error:NSError?
    var audioSession:AVAudioSession!
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    init() {
        self.audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        var categoryError:NSError?
        var activeError:NSError?
        //        set category cho audio session
        self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError)


        //        set active cho audio session

        var success = self.audioSession.setActive(true, error: &activeError)

        if !success {
            println("error making audio session active :\(activeError)")
        }
    }

    func playSound(withName:String, ext:String) {
        //       Lay song path
        if let songPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(withName, ofType: ext) {

            if let songURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: songPath) {

                var songError:NSError?

                //        Tao audioplayer

                self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: songURL, error: &songError)



                self.player.numberOfLoops = 0
                self.player.play()
            }



        }




    }
}
```

when i wan to use the function i will use:

```
SoundPlayer.sharedInstance.playSound("restart", ext: "wav")
```