# Play a sound when bluetooth is ON : no sound (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, bluetooth

I am programming a Bluetooth sensor with iOS Swift, and would like to play a sound when **Bluetooth** is connected and the sensor is working. For example, when temperature is too high, a sound alert should beep.

However, for some reason, the **sound is silent** even though the playSound() function seems to be working : we see the println message "Playing Audio (Test line. Did this line appear in the console ?)" from the console.

I wonder whether Bluetooth will block AVAudioPlayer from working. How to make the sound ?

The code is such programmed that the sound should always beep as long as Bluetooth is on. I noticed an interesting phenomenon : 
**At the moment when the Bluetooh is turned off, the sound beeps once.**
At the moment when the App is put to background (push the iPhone Home button), the sound beeps once.
I kind of have the feeling that Bluetooth blocked the AVAudioPlayer, therefore, at the moment Bluetooth is turned off, AVAudioPlayer grabbed this chance to work **once**.

Thanks
Bill

```
func playSound(){
    println("Playing Audio (Test line. Did this line appear in the console ?)")
    // Set the sound file name & extension
    var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Mario", ofType: "mp3")!)

    // Preperation
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    // Play the sound
    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {

    //self.statusLabel.text = "Connected"


    if characteristic.UUID == IRTemperatureDataUUID {
        // read parameters
        let allValues = Sensor.getTemperatureData(characteristic.value)
        self.temperatureData = allValues[0]
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        self.playSound()
}
```

Comment: Does Control Center show that it's using bluetooth for audio (it'll appear in the airplay box)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - AVAudioPlayer, sound doesn't play correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911968/swift-avaudioplayer-sound-doesnt-play-correctly)